# VBS: Read virtual (Bluetooth) Comport parameters

Tags: vbscript, bluetooth, serial-port, virtual

Good Evening,

I want to build a VBS function that returns the port number of the outgoing port for a particular device name.

EDIT:
I have started to piece together the direction I need to go in.  I'm using the script below to see if I can find all the pieces I need to confidently select the right port.  The ONE piece missing is I need to be certain I'm using the "Outgoing" port.  Right now the incoming and outgoing ports look the same with the properties I'm returning, except the comport number...

```
    Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_SerialPort")
    For Each objItem in colItems
        sOut = ""
        sOut= "Description: " & objItem.Description & vbnewline
        sout = sout & "Device ID: " & objItem.DeviceID & vbnewline
        sout = sout & "Name: " & objItem.Name & vbnewline
        sout = sout & "Caption: " & objItem.Caption & vbnewline
        sout = sout & "P'n'P Device ID: " & objItem.PNPDeviceID
        msgbox sOut
    Next
    msgbox "done"
```

Maybe I have to use a different angle to get the info on if its an incoming or outgoing port?

Comment: Could you show us the progress you have made so far with your script? There are a few different ways to do this with vbscript.

Comment: I added what I can.  I hope it gives you an idea of the angle I want to take this.  basically its the client.DiscoverDevices line from the C# example I really need the vbs equivalent for...  expecting it will be more that a couple lines  ;)

Comment: I added another snippet.  This time a small script I'm using to narrow down the properties I need to read to get all the pieces.  The one thing I'm missing is if I am reading the incoming or outgoing port....